# How can I prove that $a^m-1|a^n-1 \Leftrightarrow m|n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $(a,m,n)\in \mathbb{N}^{3}$, as $a>1$

How can I prove that $a^m-1|a^n-1 \Leftrightarrow m|n$?

I proved that $m|n \implies a^m-1|a^n-1$, but I couldn't prove the reciproque.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486626/if-am-1-mid-an-1-then-m-mid-n and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413473/showing-that-an-1-am-1-iff-n-m

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/156646

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $a^m-1\mid a^n-1$. I claim $m\mid n$. Write $n=qm+r$ for $0\leq r<m$. Then notice
$$
a^n-1=(a^{qm+r}-a^r)+(a^r-1)=a^r(a^{qm}-1)+(a^r-1).
$$
But $m\mid qm$, so by your previous work, you know $a^m-1\mid a^{qm}-1$. This implies
$a^m-1\mid a^r-1$. But $a^m-1>a^r-1$ since $m>r$ and $a>1$, so necessarily $a^r-1=0$, or $r=0$. Thus $m\mid n$.

Answer (score 1):

From different perspective, we can show by group theory.

it is enough to know that roots of $x^k-1$ is a group with $k$ elements.

suppose $x^m-1$ | $x^n-1$ that means that every root of first polynomial is also a root of second polynomial.

That means a group of $n$ elements include a group of $m$ elements by lagrange theorem; $m$| $n$.